# How to click/submit onclick values in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a question about the Selenium Python code I'm writing.
The website has a bunch of time slots, and I'm trying to simulate a mouse click, specifically targeting the 8:30-11:30 timeslot.

Here is a snippet the html:

```
    <div class="item-link" onclick="$('#SelectedStartTime').val('2015/10/16 08:30:00');$('#frmTimes').submit();">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="title">8:30 AM-11:30 AM
                <span class="available">(Spaces: <strong class="num">20</strong>)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-link" onclick="$('#SelectedStartTime').val('2015/10/16 09:00:00');$('#frmTimes').submit();">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="title">9:00 AM-12:00 PM
                <span class="available">(Spaces: <strong class="num">20</strong>)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried targeting the "8:30 AM-11:30 AM" text,

```
Time0830 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("title")
for each in Time0830:
    if "8:30 AM-11:30 AM" in each.text:
        each.click()
        break

for each in Time0830:
    if each.text == "8:30 AM-11:30 AM"
        each.click()
        break
```

Both do not do anything.

I've also tried targeting the onclick based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691126/find-and-click-an-item-from-onclick-partial-value).

```
Time0830 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@onclick,"8:30 AM-11:30 AM")]')
print (Time0830)
Time0830.click()
```

This resulted in Error: NoSuchElementException

```
Time0830 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[onclick*='8:30 AM-11:30 AM']")
print(Time0830)
Time0830.click()
```

This also resulted in `Error: NoSuchElementException`.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

**EDIT!!**
Thanks for the help on xpath help. I think the problem was also that I could not get it to click.
I've been using .click(), but it's not working any more. 
My code is now:

```
time.sleep(1.5)
Time0830 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class = "item-link" and .//div[@class = "title" and contains(text(),"8:30 PM-11:30 PM")]]').click()
```

But the page does not move, still. I have time.sleep to account for loading time. 
I've tried it without the click() and it seems to find an element. Am I finding the wrong element, or using the wrong function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you would match a `div` with `item-link` class that has a descendant `div` element having `8:30 AM-11:30 AM` text:

```
//div[@class = "item-link" and .//div[@class = "title" and contains(., "8:30 AM-11:30 AM")]]
```