# cannot locate link in table using python3 with selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath

Hi all I am using Python 3.0 and I am trying to click on a link in a table.

At current I cannot locate the link, so I cannot click on it.

Below is the html of the selected element

**Apologies here is a better example of the code...**

```
<div id="divMyActivities2" originalheight="125px" style="overflow-y:auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:451px;height:125px;">
        <table id="tblMyActivities" class="podborder" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="overflow-y: auto; table-layout: fixed; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-top: none; width: 100%; border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 0px">
<tr>
    <td class="customheader" style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 100%; color: #004a78; background: #e6ebf1 !important; font-size: 11px;" align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Type of Activity</b>
                </td>
    <td class="customheader" style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 50px; color: #004a78; background: #e6ebf1 !important; font-size: 11px;" align="center"><b>Past Due</b>
                </td>
    <td class="customheader" style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 60px; color: #004a78; background: #e6ebf1 !important; font-size: 11px;" align="center"><b>This Week</b>
                </td>
    <td class="customheader" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; font-size: 11px; width: 50px; color: #004a78; background: #e6ebf1 !important;" align="center"><b>All</b>
                </td>
</tr>
<tr class="blacktext">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; text-align: left; width: 100%;">&nbsp;
                    <img src="../../common/images/cwtoday_bullet.gif" border="0" />
                    <label onclick="pageNav('crmSales');" class="tablelink">CRM / Sales Activities</label>
                </td>
    <td id="tdSalesPastDue" class="tabletext" style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 50px;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tdSalesThisWeek" class="tabletext" style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 60px;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tdSalesAll" class="tabletext" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 50px;" align="center">&nbsp;
                </td>
</tr>
<tr id="trProjAct" class="blacktext">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; text-align: left; width: 100%; background: #f6f6f6;">&nbsp
                    <img src="../../common/images/cwtoday_bullet.gif" border="0" />
                    <label onclick="pageNav('projectActs');" class="tablelink">Project Tickets</label>
                </td>
    <td id="tdPrjActPastDue" class="tabletext" style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 50px; background: #f6f6f6;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tdPrjActThisWeek" class="tabletext" style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 60px; background: #f6f6f6;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tdPrjActAll" class="tabletext" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 50px; background: #f6f6f6;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="blacktext">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; text-align: left; width: 100%;">&nbsp;
                    <img src="../../common/images/cwtoday_bullet.gif" border="0" />
                    <label onclick="pageNav('projectIssues');" class="tablelink">Project Issues</label>
                </td>
    <td id="tdPrjIssPastDue" class="tabletext" style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 50px;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tdPrjIssThisWeek" class="tabletext" style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 60px;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tdPrjIssAll" class="tabletext" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 50px;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="blacktext">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; text-align: left; width: 100%; background: #f6f6f6;">&nbsp;
                    <img src="../../common/images/cwtoday_bullet.gif" border="0" />
                    <label onclick="pageNav('serviceRequests');" class="tablelink">Service Tickets</label>
                </td>
    <td id="tdSRPastDue" class="tabletext" style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 50px; background: #f6f6f6;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tdSRThisWeek" class="tabletext" style="border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 60px; background: #f6f6f6;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="tdSRAll" class="tabletext" align="center" style="width: 50px; background: #f6f6f6; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

**I am trying to select this element:**

```
<label onclick="pageNav('serviceRequests');" class="tablelink">Service Tickets</label>
```

**What I have Tried....**

**Tried:**

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Tickets').click()
```

**Exception:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Tickets"
```

**Tried:**

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Service Tickets').click()
```

**Exception:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Service Tickets"
```

**Tried**

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tablelink")
```

**Outcome:**

```
produces an empty list "[]"
```

**Tried:**

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("label")
```

**Exception:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"label"}
```

I found this URL but I could not alter the code : [Find and click an item from 'onclick' partial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691126/find-and-click-an-item-from-onclick-partial-value)

- Wild Guess I tired to decode from the link

**Tried:**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tablelink[onclick*='Service Tickets']")
```

**Exception:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"tablelink[onclick*='Service Tickets']"}
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: You may provide your HTML part so that we can understand what's actually should be. Your code and HTML does not seem to match.

Comment: Check if element is in an iframe. Make sure you wait for the element if needed and try using a css selector like: "label[onclick*=serviceRequests]"

Answer (score 0):

Apolgoes still learning this all.

I had to switch Iframe then I was able to to locate the code by XPATH.

I didn't want to paste the entire code at once as it was pages long to delve through.

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("gwt-Frame"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(.,'Service Tickets')]").click()
```

Thanks for your time.