# How to find element using onclick in selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, onclick

My HTML:

```
<tr>
            <td width="5%" align="center" height="25">&nbsp;1</td>
            <td width="20%" height="25">&nbsp;&nbsp;Mahamoodha Bi H</td>
            <td width="5%" align="center" height="25">&nbsp;356159</td>
            <td width="5%" align="center" height="25">&nbsp;Female</td>
            <td width="10%" align="center" height="25">&nbsp;32 Years</td>
            <td width="15%" align="center" height="25">&nbsp;22/09/2021 03:00 PM</td>
            <td width="15%" height="25">&nbsp;01/10/2021 03:53 PM</td>
            <td width="15%" height="25" align="center">&nbsp;01/10/2021 12:14 PM</td>
            <td width="5%" height="25" align="center">
              <img class="imgButtonStyle" src="../../images/continue.png" onclick="loadDischargeSummaryListDetails('3163','356159',1);" width="20" height="20">
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I have a list of rows like the one above. I need to iterate through the rows and click on the last column of each row to get the data I need and close the same. I am new to python and selenium and not sure how to go about it.

The only unique data are the data in the third column, which is a ID number and the "onclick" value in "img" tag on the last column. The other data repeat either in every row or in some rows.

I have collected these separately using beautifulsoup.

1. I was able to find the ID number element using the code below but I don't know how to use this to click on the last element of the row.

   ```
   selection = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(ID))
   ```
2. I got the 'onclick' value, but I don't know how to search for the clickable element using the value. I tried the code below, but it throws a "InvalidSelectorException" error.

   ```
   selection = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@onclick=\"{}\")]".format(onclick))
   ```

I am stuck here and don't know how to select and click the element.

I solved it by using the following code:

```
#Select the table 
tab = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ipDischargeView > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1)')
#Find the total number of rows containing the imgButtonStyle
raw_list = len(tab.find_elements_by_class_name('imgButtonStyle'))
for n in range(0,raw_list):
    
    #freshly search the page each iteration for the same table
    tab = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ipDischargeView > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1)')

    #Select the particular row from the list
    patient = tab.find_elements_by_class_name('imgButtonStyle')[n]
```

Is there a more simple or elegant way to do this? This seems quite repetitive and inefficient

Comment: I think this post can help you: [find-and-click-an-item-from-onclick-partial-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691126/find-and-click-an-item-from-onclick-partial-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to reach to the last column (last list element) is like this:

```py
selection = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'{}')]//parent::tr//td".format(ID))[-1]
```

With this line of code, first you determine the location of ID, then return to the `tr` HTML element and then get the last `td` within the `tr`.

Comment: `selection = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'{}')]//parent::tr//td".format(ID))[-1]` The square bracket was in the wrong place. Otherwise this works fine

Comment: Oops, sorry for that. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned that you want to iterate over the rows, try like below once:

Get the locator that highlights all the `tr` tags of the table. And iterate over them to find details.

Use a `.` at the beginning of the `xpath` to find element within an element.

```
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath for tr tags") # Should highlight all the `tr` tags

for row in table:
    id = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[3]").text # Assuming that the 3rd `td` tag contains the ID
    onclick = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//img").get_attribute("onclick") # Gets the value of onclick.
```